# Modx can't send message with FormIt

Tags: email, modx, formit

I try to send a message from my contact form, but I don't receive any message.

I use QuickEmail to test it, and I receive a message on my mailtrap account. I guess the problem is from the contact form (right now I am local).

```
//Chunk
[[!FormIt?
   &hooks=`spam,email,redirect`
   &emailTpl=`MyEmailChunk`
   &emailTo=`test@gmail.com`
   &redirectTo=`123`
]]

<form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" class="form">
        <input class="mb-4" type="text" placeholder="NAME" id="name" />
        <input class="mb-4" type="text" placeholder="EMAIL" id="email" />
        <textarea class="mb-4" type="text" placeholder="MESSAGE" id="message"></textarea>   
        <button class="btn btn-success">SUBMIT</button>  
</form>

//Second chunk
Name: [[+input-name]] <br/>
Email: [[+input-email]] <br/>
Message: <br /> 
[[+input-textare]]
<br/>
Agreement check: [[+input-checkbox]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use SMTP? This maybe important also, please enable it. It offen depends on server settings.so If I understood this properly and you really use local server  - all that makes sense also.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the ***name*** parameter, which is required.

```
<input name="input-name" class="mb-4" type="text" placeholder="NAME" id="name" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefname